# Checking the first few characters in a string

Tags: python, string

I would like to check the first few characters (the numbers are variable) in a string. 
E.g.

```
a = '+6221-123-4567'
```

and I would like to check if the first few characters are in

```
b = ['021', '+6221', '(021)', '(+62)']
```

I would like to do it programatically, without separating manually based on the number of characters:

```
if a[:3] in ['021']: print('yes')
if a[:5] in ['+6221', '(021)', '(+62)']: print('yes')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])
>
> Return True if string starts with the prefix, otherwise return False.
>   prefix can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for.

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Try this,
`a.startswith(tuple(b))`.

Full code,

```
if a.startswith(tuple(b)):
    print("yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
a = '+6221-123-4567'

b = ['021', '+6221', '(021)', '(+62)']

b = [i[1:-1] if "(" in i else i for i in b]

#you can generate a list of characters:

new_list = [a[:5][:i+1] for i in range(5) if a[:5][:i+1] in b]

print(new_list)

if len(new_list) > 0:
   print "yes"

else:
    print "no"
```

Output:

```
['+62', '+6221']

yes
```